# Stack overflow in XBAP app using Ninject

Tags: c#, wpf, ninject, xbap, ninject-extensions

When I use Ninject with any extension in XBAP (WPF Browser) application, I get Stack Overflow exception (small pun intended).

Here's stack trace. It's rather large, but complete (that's why I've posted it on pastebin):

http://pastebin.com/su9M1c7V

I'm trying to use Conventions and Factory extensions for Ninject. If I reference assembly of either one, I get Stack overflow exception. So to be clear, when I remove references to both libraries, application runs correctly.

It's really weird, because Ninject seems to be creating new AppDomain, but CLR apparently tries to load entry/executing assembly (the only one in my solution) and execute it. That obviously leads to Stack overflow exception.

I'm also using **Caliburn.Micro**, plus additional libraries: **Caliburn.Micro.Contrib**, **Caliburn.Micro.Extras** (along with their dependencies) - all latest versions.

Does anyone have an idea, what's causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around with AppDomains, I've found out that Ninject has nothing to do with this.

**(an extensive explanation follows, solution/workaround is at the end of the answer)**

Ninject creates seperate `AppDomain` in `AssemblyNameRetriever` to retrieve assembly names. In my case, those assemblies are Ninject extensions:

```
private static AppDomain CreateTemporaryAppDomain()
{
    return AppDomain.CreateDomain(
        "NinjectModuleLoader",
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence,
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation);
}
```

The problem lies with the object `AppDomainSetup` stored in  `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation` property. It has `ActivationArguments` property set to instance of `ActivationArguments` class, which contains information that causes entry assembly to execute (which is fine, since XBAP application has to start somehow).

However, since Ninject uses same setup information, this causes infinite recursion and thus our favorite **StackOverflow** exception.

The workaround is to set property `ActivationArguments` to `null`. However, `AppDomain` class creates a copy of `AppDomainSetup` object in `SetupInformation` property getter. Thus it is necessary to get a copy of `AppDomainSetup` object, set `ActivationArguments` to `null` and via **reflection** set value `_FusionStore` field of `AppDomain` class to this object.

**TL;DR**:
Before creating Ninject kernel, we have to invoke this code:

```
var setupInformation = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation;
setupInformation.ActivationArguments = null;

var field = typeof(AppDomain).GetField("_FusionStore", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
field.SetValue(AppDomain.CurrentDomain, setupInformation);
```

No idea if this will cause any issues later. Thus far, I believe this code requires full trust, because it accesses private field (and sets its value).